# Inactive link_to in td or p tag

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Putting link_to between p or td tag make it inactive - it is bllue as link but I cannot click on it.

This dosn't work:

```
<table class="highlight">
                <tbody>
                @foreach($card['files'] as $index=>$file)

                    <tr>
                        <td>{!! link_to('file/'.$file['path'], $file['description']) !!} {{ $file['mime'] }}</td>
                    </tr>
            @endforeach
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

and this either

```
                    <p>{!! link_to($file['path'], $file['description']) !!}</p>
```

Rendered HTML:
[image]

but after I remove tags it works OK.

Comment: Can you also add the rendered HTML, so we can see what this outputs?

Comment: Looks like completely valid HTML code. Guess this is more a client problem, then a laravel problem. Did you check with a validator? Does the right click work on it? Maybe you disabled pointer-events via CSS?

Comment: @Kjell No blocking js or css in included. It event dosn't show as link (pointer cursor) on rendered view.

Comment: Can you create a JSBin with the output? How about the validation? Still believing it's a client side problem...

Comment: @Kjell ok, you were right with css. I have button on the left and it was covering whole site width.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was from button on the left which coverted all site width.
[image]